# What are the intel hex records type 03 or 05 doing in iHex program for ARM?

Tags: arm, hex, objcopy

What are the intel hex records type 03 or 05 doing in iHex program?

> Record type **03: Start Segment Address**     For **80x86** processors, specifies the initial content of the CS:IP registers. The address field is 0000, the byte count is 04, the first two bytes are the CS value, the latter two are the IP value.
>
> Record type **05: Start Linear Address**  The address field is 0000 (not used) and the byte count is 04. The four data bytes represent the 32-bit value loaded into the EIP register of the **80386** and higher CPU.

Do these even make sense for an ARM program?

Whenever I generate .hex to program embedded ARM, the ending looks something like this:

> :10851400B4040020BC040020BC040020C4040020D7
>   :10852400C4040020CC040020CC040020D404002087
>   :10853400D4040020DC040020DC040020E404002037
>   :10854400E4040020EC040020EC040020F4040020E7
>   :10855400F4040020FC040020FC040020FFFFFFFFC3
>   :048564000000020011
>   :040000**05**08002910B6
>   :00000001FF

I've edited the programming app to ignore this record, and just today a coworker reported his compiler produced a **03** type record on the second-to-last line, which prevented programming the MPU.

Why does objcopy create these records? Can I stop it from doing it?

Relevant Makefile lines:

```
 FORMAT = ihex
 OBJCOPY = arm-elf-objcopy

  %.hex: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_FLASH) $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O $(FORMAT) $< $@
```

Comment: [ARM's page here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka9903.html) has some ARM-specific interpretation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do these even make sense for an ARM program?

An ARM program will always have an entry point set, even if you provided a vector table in the bare metal case.

The `arm-*-objcopy` program is not very intelligent and just produces the `03` record when the entry address is within the first megabyte for compatibility reasons, and the `05` otherwise.

A flash tool can safely ignore these record types on bare metal ARM, because the vector table contains the required addresses already. You could try filtering the hex file to remove these records, e.g. using `sed`.

Comment: Good to know! I tried to find documentation of objcopy regarding this behavior as it also surprised me on a different target, similarly breaking a tool when it encountered one of these types.